# What's the smallest non-$p$ group that isn't a semidirect product?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Although every non-simple group can be described as a [group extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension), it is well-known that not every non-simple group can be expressed as a semidirect product of smaller groups.

For example, a cyclic group of order $p^2$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but cannot be written as a semidirect product.  The quaternion group $Q_8$ is also not a semidirect product.  Indeed, this seems to be very common property for $p$-groups.

So my question is:

> What's the smallest non-simple group $G$ such that:
>
> - $G$ isn't a $p$-group, and
> - $G$ can't be expressed as a semidirect product of smaller groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(48,28)$, which is a group that is similar to ${\rm GL}(2,3)$ but has no non-central elements of order $2$? It is one of the two Schur covering groups $2 \cdot S_4$ of $S_4$ (the other one being ${\rm GL}(2,3)$).

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: According to my magma computation, Derek is right and, SmallGroup(48,28) is the correct answer. (SL(2,5) is the second smallest and (144,31) the third smallest.)

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yes, it is an answer to the question. I was politely disputing the claim that ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ is the correct answer! Sorry to be confusing!

Comment: You are correct.  There was a bug in my GAP code!